# Accessing elements of a matrix within a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a function:

```
LUD(A)
```

Which applies a LU decomposition algorithm on a matrix A. Now i have to return the lower and upper matrices, U and L. To do this I used:

```
return(list(U=U,L=L))
```

The problem I am having is actually accessing the elements of this list. Now I can call U with;

```
U<-LUD(A)[1]
```

However this sets U as a list of length 1, whereas I obviously want it as a matrix. I read that I can access the elements of the list using U[[1,1]], however this returns the error:

```
Error in U[[1, 2]] : incorrect number of subscripts
```

I also tried using the function;

```
as.matrix(U)
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You extract elements using double brackets.  You would only use two indices if the list itself had dimensions like a matrix, but it doesn't.  It's almost always better to use names for extraction, for future-proofing.

So you want

```
both <- LUD(A)
U <- both[["U"]]
```

but you could use

```
U <- both[[1]]
```

if your definition of the result doesn't change.  You can also use

```
U <- both$U
```

Note that `$` does partial name matching (e.g. it would match `U1`, not just `U`, if `U` happened to be missing).  That seems like it saves typing, but in the long run it's not good to rely on it:  you might have `U1` and not `U` now, but in the future when you add `U` suddenly you'll extract that instead of `U1`.